# The verb "roll" here : meaning in a context

Tags: word-usage

Reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/covid-case-spike-united-states-texas-arizona-north-carolina-coronavirus-201958682.html) there is a line

> A June 9 Federal Emergency Management Agency document shows the same spike in cases. The **rolling** average of deaths in the U.S., per the FEMA document, is starting to trend up over 1,000 per day.

I checked with my dictionary, and it is apparent from the context it is the intransitive(if I have to paste all the definitions including transitive, there would be too long question(sorry), but would you kindly confirm if the definition might be **4 b**?

---

intransitive verb

> 1
>
> a :  to move forward along a surface by rotation
>    --the ball rolled along the floor--
>
> b (1) :  to turn over and over

--the children rolled in the grass, or waded in the brook — Henry Adams--
--the dog rolled in the mud--

> (2) :  to luxuriate in an abundant supply :  wallow — used with in

--tragic to think that a man may be short of money whilst his children are rolling in it — J. D. Sheridan--

> c :  to move onward or around as if by completing a revolution

--the months roll on--
--five summers have rolled round since then — Douglass Cater--

> elapse, pass

--the years roll by — Fortnight--

> d :  to move in an orbit

--the planets roll around the sun--

> 2
>   a :  to look in one direction after another in quick succession :  to shift the gaze continually

--a pair of eyes which rolled with malevolent curiosity — T. B. Costain--

> b archaic :  to revolve in the mind
>
> c :  to revolve on or as if on an axis

--long has the globe been rolling round — Walt Whitman--

> 3
>   :  to move about :  roam, wander
>
> 4
>   a :  to flow with a rising and falling motion

--the waves roll on--
--the clouds roll past--

> :  go forward in an easy, gentle, or undulating manner

--mists rolling down the mountain — Irish Digest--
--the fog, which from the foot of the lawn rolled away … like a sea — R. M. Lovett--

> **b :  to flow in a continuous stream :  to arrive, become produced, or become received in abundant quantities or amount :  pour**

--cars rolling off the assembly line--
--delegates rolled in from all parts of the country--
--the money was rolling in--

> c :  to flow as part of a stream of words

--catchy phrases, and sharp retorts that roll so freely from the tongues of the people he characterizes — H. H. Reichard--

> d :  to have an undulating contour :  display a gently rising and falling surface

--most of it is prairie, but the prairie rolls and dips and curves — Sinclair Lewis--

> e :  to lie extended :  stretch

--the flowers rolled away in dizzy unbroken patterns to the horizon — Alan Moorehead--
--to the west and south roll the grainfields — O. A. Fitzgerald--

> 5
>   a :  to become carried in a vehicle

--got in the car and were soon rolling at high speed--

> b :  to become carried on a stream

--the scattered debris rolled down the flooded river--

> c :  to move on wheels

--with a smooth hard-packed surface of snow, trucks can roll right along — Harold Griffin--

> 6
>   a :  to make a deep reverberating sound

--the thunder rolls--
--the drums roll--
--a roar from the crowd rolled all around enveloping us — A. P. Gaskell--

> b :  to make a deep and sonorous sound

--listen to a rich voice which rolled out into the dusk — Margaret Kennedy--

> c :  trill — used of a bird
>
> 7
>
> a :  to incline first to one side and then to the other :  swing from side to side

--the ship still heaved and rolled on the heavy sea — C. S. Forester--
--as he swam he rolled like a sick fish — Kenneth Roberts--

> b :  to walk with a swinging gait :  sway

--a heavy elderly peasant rolled in his gait — F. M. Ford--

> c :  to move so as to cushion the impact of a blow — used with with

--rolled with the punch, but it caught his nose nevertheless — Edwin Corle--

> 8
>   a :  to take the form of a cylinder or ball

--this cloth rolls unevenly--
--laid my tarp on the ground and rolled up in every blanket I had — Ysabel Rennie--

> b :  to respond to rolling in a specified way :  be in a specified condition after being rolled

--the tennis court rolled easily after the shower--
--the metal rolled out in flat bars--

> 9
>   a :  to get under way :  begin to move

--the fire engines rolled while the alarm bell was still ringing--
--the company commander gave the signal to roll and the tanks moved out--

> b :  to move forward :  develop and maintain impetus

--not enough real sting in demand to get business rolling at the speed many steelmakers had hoped for — Wall Street Journal--
--rolled to a fourth term — Time--
--the team was held scoreless during the third period, but in the fourth period they started to roll again--

> c :  to go into action or operation

--the cameras were ready to roll--
--the presses started to roll--

> d :  to go to press

--they went home after the late edition had rolled--

> 10
>   a :  bowl
>
> b :  to execute a forward or backward roll in tumbling

Comment: You could have saved yourself some trouble by only concentrating on rolling, the adjective....Also, try googling: rolling average.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is much too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That definition may be the origin of this *rolling*, but it's not really the meaning.  In this context, *rolling* is not a present progressive verb, but an adjective:

> **rolling** adjective
>
> : not having or set to a fixed date or deadline : continually adjustable through a period of time to provide flexibility for individual circumstances
>
> // De Blasio's spokesman Wiley Norvell said the city is encouraging families to sign up their kids by June 26, although there is a *rolling* deadline until Oct. 1. The sooner families apply, he said, the better chance they'll secure the seat they want.— Matthew Chayes
>
> // Many law school use a *rolling* admissions process, meaning they evaluate applications as they come in and release admissions decisions, one by one.— Ilana Kowarski
>
> // The Delaware Aglands Foundation Board announced it will institute a *rolling* application process for its Young Farmer Loan Program to offer young farmers more flexibility in acquiring a farm. — The Dover Post

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rolling

Because *rolling* is an adjective, not a present participle, we don't say things like "the average rolls" or "the deadline rolls."

Answer (score 2):

"Rolling" here refers to an average that reflects a certain time period.  As one day "rolls" onto the report, the oldest one "rolls" off.

So a 7 day rolling average calculated today, June 11th, would include June 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, and 11.  The same report calculated tomorrow would include June 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, and 12.